# How to get the remote user from httpd basic authentication in my tomcat servlet?

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat7, http-basic-authentication, mod-proxy-ajp

I've successfully configured mod_proxy_ajp from my httpd to Tomcat, with httpd performing the SSL and basic authentication.  I need the remote user in my tomcat application, so I thought using AJP would population the headers so HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser() would give me the username, but it is 'null'.  However HttpServletRequest.getRemoteHost() is populated correctly.

What do I need to do to get the remote user from httpd basic authentication in my tomcat servlet?

Comment: Found the answer... [Forward REMOTE_USER to tomcat via AJP][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749065/forward-remote-user-to-tomcat-via-ajp-e-g-for-shibboleth

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer on StackOverflow... [Forward REMOTE_USER to tomcat via AJP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749065/forward-remote-user-to-tomcat-via-ajp-e-g-for-shibboleth)

Bottom line is you must add `tomcatAuthentication="false"` to your AJP connector.

The default...

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

...becomes...

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" tomcatAuthentication="false" />
```